# Using sed to replace a part of multine text and returning non 0 code when not finding a replacement

Tags: linux, sed

im trying to switch the `no` part from the below text to `yes` using this sed command but doesnt seem to figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

command: `sed -E "s@<wodle name="docker-listener">\n\s+<disabled>(no)<\/disabled>@yes@g" /etc/test.txt`

text in test.txt

```
<wodle name="docker-listener">
    <disabled>no</disabled>
</wodle>

<wodle name="example">
    <disabled>no</disabled>
</wodle>
```

**UPDATE:**
Im in a better shape now with the below command, but the problem is that even if sed does not find a match im still get a return code of `0` and not the defined `100`. Any clues how to fix this?

`sed -E "N;!{q100};s@<wodle name=\"docker-listener\">\n\s+<disabled>no@<wodle name=\"docker-listener\">\n   <disabled>yes@g"`

Comment: Please [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858). I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Comment: sed normally works on a single line so embedded `\n`won't match unless you tell sed to read multiple lines into the pattern space

Comment: sed '/<disabled>/ s/no/yes/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed  'H;1h;$!d;x;{/(<wodle name="docker-listener">\n[ ]*<disabled>)no(<\/disabled>)/!q100; s//\1yes\2/}' -E file; echo $?

0

sed  'H;1h;$!d;x;{/(<wodle name="docker-listener">\n[ ]*<disabled>)yes(<\/disabled>)/!q100; s//\1yes\2/}' -E file; echo $?

100
```

Since you insisted on matching \n and [[:space:]]; Storing entire file in buffer is only solution to match \n.

`H;1h;$!d;x` --> Store entire file in pattern buffer

`/<wodle name="docker-listener">\n[ ]*<disabled>yes<\/disabled>/` --> Match for pattern

`!{q100}` --> sets exit code 100 if pattern not found else 0

`s///` ---> will do actual replace

Comment: hey thank you for your reply! The first one wont do because i have many similar blocks, the second one works but i still have the same problem of not returning a non `0` code when NOT replacing anything. The below still returns `0` when not replacing `sed -i 'H;1h;$!d;x;!{q100};s@\(<wodle name="docker-listener">\n[ ]*<disabled>\)yes\(</disabled>\)@\1yes\2@' /etc/test2.txt`

Comment: check again new answer

Comment: Thank you for saving me hours of researching! Do you know as to why the `"` dont work tho? Im curious and i had a feeling that was a big part of the issue... e.g. `sed  "H;1h;$!d;x;{/(<wodle name=\"docker-listener\">\n[ ]*<disabled>)yes(<\/disabled>)/!q100; s//\1yes\2/}" -E i; echo $?
`

Comment: because " " will not escape ! which is used for history substitution. Try 1) Change ! to "\!" or 2) set +H to disabled history expansion